# How to globally load types from a package that typically isn't globally-loaded?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I prefer to use `import` only to include actual functionality in a file, and to use my `tsconfig` to include all necessary types.

Here's an example reducer within my app:

```
import { createReducer } from '@ngrx/store';

const initialState: State = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
);

export function appReducer(state: State, action: Action): State {
  return reducer(state, action);
}
```

I've declared `State` in `custom_types/typings.d.ts`, and have included `custom_types` within `tsconfig.compileOptions.typeRoots`. This works fine.

`Action` is undefined. I could include `Action` in the `import` statement, but since it's only used for typing and not for functionality, I would prefer to include it through my `tsconfig`.

I've tried to globally include `@ngrx` typings in several ways:

- Adding `@ngrx/store` to `typeRoots`
- Adding `@ngrx/store/index.d.ts` to `typeRoots`
- Adding `import '@ngrx/store'` to `custom_types/typings.d.ts`

But the compiler continues to say that `Action` is undefined.

How can I globally include all `@ngrx` typings in my project?

Answer (score 1):

In `custom_types/global-types.d.ts`:

```js
type Action = import("@ngrx/store").Action
```

or

```js
import * as store from "@ngrx/store"

declare global {
  type Action = store.Action
}
```